# Nginx appears to show old version of site

Tags: tomcat, caching, amazon-web-services, nginx

Recently came across a very strange issue. We're using Amazon CodeDeploy for deploying our Java app to the backend webservers. It was working fine for awhile then noticed that our site kept showing an old version (not latest code).

After many hours of going back and forth with AWS we learned that CodeDeploy was fine and working as expected. So what was the problem?

I managed to check out tomcat and see our changes were getting deployed to tomcat properly without any errors. The only thing that is left....our load balancer (Nginx).

I've set **`expires off ;`** inside the virtual host file

I have also set **`sendfile off;`** in the nginx.conf file

At this point, I'm pretty much at a loss and not sure what else to try....

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Clarification:**
I am using Elastic Nginx (https://github.com/rochacon/elastic-nginx) which is responsible for keeping the upstreams (IPs) updated inside Nginx in case any backend webapp server fails. I've checked the upstreams and see 2 entries for each webapp server, so seems that is fine.

**Nginx configuration:**

> nginx version: nginx/1.6.2 built by gcc 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat
>   4.8.2-16) (GCC)  TLS SNI support enabled configure arguments: --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/fastcgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/uwsgi --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/scgi --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/lock/subsys/nginx --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-file-aio --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_spdy_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_degradation_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_perl_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-pcre --with-google_perftools_module --with-debug --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' --with-ld-opt=' -Wl,-E'

**Nginx.conf**

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 22;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

 http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile off;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    client_max_body_size 15M;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
# gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

   #upstream backend {
   #    server 128.199.57.231;
   #    server 104.236.50.190;
   #    server 10.0.0.3:80;
   #}
   #server {
   #        listen 80;
   #location / {
   #            proxy_pass http://backend;
   #        }
   #    }

    }
```

Comment: Sorry but where are configuration and log files?

Comment: I guess you're referring to these?
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf    
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

Comment: yes, it depends on type of installation, manually or from a repo.

Comment: I'm using Amazon Linux AMI and was done from repo

Comment: I manually copied the WAR file to each instance, start/stop tomcat, and checked the folders to see that the changes were inside. Which makes me think it's Nginx...(even powered off instances) and website was still showing while Nginx was up....rather strange :)

Comment: Let's try to check whether */etc/init.d/nginx stop* makes Nginx stop listening a port?

Comment: Yes, when i run /etc/init.d/nginx stop it stops listening and the site is unreachable.

Comment: Is it helpful if I provide my Nginx configuration?

Comment: Yes, this is only way to help you. Check which configuration file in use by **nginx -V**.

Comment: Thanks, I just ran that command and included output above as well as nginx.conf file

Comment: @Anatoly any ideas with the config? I even turned off the cache control to no and still wasn't working.... :(